# Why does Ezra have to run for Kanan to force-throw him?

Tags: star-wars, the-force, star-wars-rebels

In several of the Rebels episodes, in order to cross a chasm or gap of some sort Ezra will run towards the gap and jump at which point Kanan uses the force to augment Ezra's jump and throw him across the gap.

My question is why does Ezra have to run and jump at all, why can't Kanan just throw (or more carefully move) him all the way across?  It seems that the added component of Ezra running and jumping just introduces more complexity and danger to the task.

It can't have anything to do with Kanan not having the strength to move Ezra, as in S3E11 immediately after using this method to send Ezra across a gap Kanan uses the force to hold a massive rock bridge in place across the gap while Zeb and Saw walk across.

Comment: Because going from zero mph to 30mph in one go is sufficient to kill you?

Comment: I suspect this makes things easier on Kanan.

Answer (score 3):

> It can't have anything to do with Kanan not having the strength to move Ezra, as ... Kanan uses the force to hold a massive rock bridge in place

Also: *"Size matters not." - Yoda*

Recalling ESB, Luke had trouble lifting his X-Wing out of the swamp because he didn't really *believe* he could do it.  He believed enough to move it *a little bit,* but not all the way up and out.  As you've observed with the stone bridge, lifting things with the Force isn't really about strength, but about faith in your own ability to do it.

So, maybe Kannan just instinctively thinks Ezra should run in order for it "to work better" - owing no doubt to a lifetime of them both living in the grasp of mundane physics - and so Ezra runs.  The truth is that the running isn't really necessary, it's just what they *believe* is necessary for the stunt they're performing.

Answer (score 1):

Despite what Yoda says **Size matter does**

Any Jedi could move his lightsaber. Yoda is able to knock two Imperial Guards with gesture of his hand. Yet, even Yoda needs to concentrate (and close eyes) to lift heavy X-wing, or Senate pod. We don't see any Jedi or Sith throwing mountains at his enemies (at least not in Canon) .

Perhaps most telling is this scene where Dooku trains Savage Opress. Dooku is able to lift all stones, Savage only lifts some of them when he uses all of his hatred and anger. Similarly, Kanan is visibly strained and exhausted after he holds large slab of rock for Zeb and Saw. Therefore, he most likely used up all his powers to achieve that.

Although *Rebels* are not entirely consistent (it is essentially kid's show for Disney's new target audience) we do see Force users as beings with certain limits, who do get hurt or exhausted. Therefore, they do need to conserve energy and their force powers for critical moments, not to squander it for relatively trivial tasks . Kanan could move Ezra on his own, but why would he do that when Ezra has two healthy legs plus Force ability.